# Поворот карты Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Добрый день. Кто может объяснить как реализовать поворот карты? НАпример когда я нажимаю кнопку поворот вправо что бы карта не двигалась вправо а поворачивалась вокруг центральной оси вправо. Как это реализовано в Gooele Maps ? Может есть живые примеры?

Comment: =) поставил телефон на стол, нажал на стол, обошел стол на противоположную сторону - карты перевернулись, профит =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите MapsDemo в Android SDK: там была реализована возможность поворота карты.